# exponential approximation at adaboost

Tags: algorithms, approximation, adaboost

I am reading about AdaBoost algorithm,

[image: ppt]

I cannot understand (7). How can it be like this?

If you want full document, you can get it at http://cseweb.ucsd.edu/classes/fa01/cse291/AdaBoost.pdf

Answer (score 1):

They use Jensen's inequality in a finite form  to prove

exp(ax)< (1+x)/2*exp(a) + (1-x)/2*exp(-a)    (*)

Then they apply inequality (*) to each summand in (7)

To prove (*) they set convex function f(t) = exp(t)

a1 = (1+x)/2
a2 = (1-x)/2
x1 = a
x2 = -a

Then  a1+a2=1
      a1*x1 + a2*x2 = a*x